# IplImage crop and rotate - Android

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm using ffmpeg to video capture for 30 seconds.

```
@Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (yuvIplimage != null && recording && rec) 
                {
                    new SaveFrame().execute(data);
                }
            }
        }
```

save frame class is below

```
private class SaveFrame extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, File> {
            long t;
            protected File doInBackground(byte[]... arg) {

                t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - firstTime - pausedTime);
                toSaveFrames++;
                File pathCache = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/DCIM", (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L)+ "_" + toSaveFrames + ".tmp");
                BufferedOutputStream bos;
                try {
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathCache));
                    bos.write(arg[0]);
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    pathCache = null;
                    toSaveFrames--;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    pathCache = null;
                    toSaveFrames--;
                }
                return pathCache;


            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(File filename)
            {
                if(filename!=null)
                {
                    savedFrames++;
                    tempList.add(new FileFrame(t,filename));
                }
            }
        }
```

finally i add all frames with crop and rotation

```
private class AddFrame extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        private int serial = 0;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            for(int i=0; i<tempList.size(); i++)
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) tempList.get(i).file.length()];
                try {
                    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempList.get(i).file));
                    buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    buf.close();

                    IplImage image = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);

//                                      final int startY = 640*(480-480)/2;
//                                      final int lenY = 640*480;
//                                      yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(bytes, startY, lenY);
//                                      final int startVU = 640*480+ 640*(480-480)/4;
//                                      final int lenVU = 640* 480/2;
//                                      yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(bytes, startVU, lenVU);

                    if (tempList.get(i).time > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                        recorder.setTimestamp(tempList.get(i).time);
                    }

                    image = cropImage(image);
                    image = rotate(image, 270);
//                                       image = rotateImage(image);
                    recorder.record(image);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "record " + i);
                    image = null;
                    serial++;
                    publishProgress(serial);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... serial) {
            int value = serial[0];
            creatingProgress.setProgress(value);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
        {
            creatingProgress.dismiss();
            if (recorder != null && recording) {
                recording = false;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Finishing recording, calling stop and release on recorder");
                try {
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.release();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(RecordActivity.this,AnswerViewActivity.class));
                } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

my crop and rotate method are below

```
private IplImage cropImage(IplImage src)
    {
        cvSetImageROI(src, r);
        IplImage cropped = IplImage.create(imageHeight, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
        cvCopy(src, cropped);
        return cropped;
    }

    public static IplImage rotate(IplImage image, double angle) {        
        IplImage copy = opencv_core.cvCloneImage(image);

        IplImage rotatedImage = opencv_core.cvCreateImage(opencv_core.cvGetSize(copy), copy.depth(), copy.nChannels()); 
        CvMat mapMatrix = opencv_core.cvCreateMat( 2, 3, opencv_core.CV_32FC1 );

        //Define Mid Point
        CvPoint2D32f centerPoint = new CvPoint2D32f();
        centerPoint.x(copy.width()/2);
        centerPoint.y(copy.height()/2);

        //Get Rotational Matrix
        opencv_imgproc.cv2DRotationMatrix(centerPoint, angle, 1.0, mapMatrix);

        //Rotate the Image
        opencv_imgproc.cvWarpAffine(copy, rotatedImage, mapMatrix, opencv_imgproc.CV_INTER_CUBIC +  opencv_imgproc.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, opencv_core.cvScalarAll(170));
        opencv_core.cvReleaseImage(copy);
        opencv_core.cvReleaseMat(mapMatrix);        
        return rotatedImage;
    }
```

my final video crop and rotate but green frames and colored frames mixed with this.

How to fix this problem. I'm not aware of iplimage. In some blogs they mention its YUV format. first u need to convert Y and then convert UV.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: When image is rotated, image size is increase/decrease in both width and height.  recorder.record(image); need same width and height as provided at recorder initialization time.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the onPreviewFrame method of this [Open Source Android Touch-To-Record library](https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord) to take transpose and resize a captured frame.

I defined "yuvIplImage" as following in my setCameraParams() method.

```
IplImage yuvIplImage = IplImage.create(mPreviewSize.height, mPreviewSize.width, opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
```

Also initialize your videoRecorder object as following, giving width as height and vice versa.

```
//call initVideoRecorder() method like this to initialize videoRecorder object of FFmpegFrameRecorder class.
initVideoRecorder(strVideoPath, mPreview.getPreviewSize().height, mPreview.getPreviewSize().width, recorderParameters);

//method implementation
public void initVideoRecorder(String videoPath, int width, int height, RecorderParameters recorderParameters)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "initVideoRecorder");

    videoRecorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(videoPath, width, height, 1);
    videoRecorder.setFormat(recorderParameters.getVideoOutputFormat());
    videoRecorder.setSampleRate(recorderParameters.getAudioSamplingRate());
    videoRecorder.setFrameRate(recorderParameters.getVideoFrameRate());
    videoRecorder.setVideoCodec(recorderParameters.getVideoCodec());
    videoRecorder.setVideoQuality(recorderParameters.getVideoQuality());
    videoRecorder.setAudioQuality(recorderParameters.getVideoQuality());
    videoRecorder.setAudioCodec(recorderParameters.getAudioCodec());
    videoRecorder.setVideoBitrate(1000000);
    videoRecorder.setAudioBitrate(64000);
}
```

This is my onPreviewFrame() method:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{

    long frameTimeStamp = 0L;

    if(FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp == 0L && FragmentCamera.firstTime > 0L)
    {
        frameTimeStamp = 1000L * (System.currentTimeMillis() - FragmentCamera.firstTime);
    }
    else if(FragmentCamera.mLastAudioTimestamp == FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp)
    {
        frameTimeStamp = FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp + FragmentCamera.frameTime;
    }
    else
    {
        long l2 = (System.nanoTime() - FragmentCamera.mAudioTimeRecorded) / 1000L;
        frameTimeStamp = l2 + FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp;
        FragmentCamera.mLastAudioTimestamp = FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp;
    }

    synchronized(FragmentCamera.mVideoRecordLock)
    {
        if(FragmentCamera.recording && FragmentCamera.rec && lastSavedframe != null && lastSavedframe.getFrameBytesData() != null && yuvIplImage != null)
        {
            FragmentCamera.mVideoTimestamp += FragmentCamera.frameTime;

            if(lastSavedframe.getTimeStamp() > FragmentCamera.mVideoTimestamp)
            {
                FragmentCamera.mVideoTimestamp = lastSavedframe.getTimeStamp();
            }

            try
            {
                yuvIplImage.getByteBuffer().put(lastSavedframe.getFrameBytesData());

                IplImage bgrImage = IplImage.create(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height, opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);// In my case, mPreviewSize.width = 1280 and mPreviewSize.height = 720
                IplImage transposed = IplImage.create(mPreviewSize.height, mPreviewSize.width, yuvIplImage.depth(), 4);
                IplImage squared = IplImage.create(mPreviewSize.height, mPreviewSize.height, yuvIplImage.depth(), 4);

                int[] _temp = new int[mPreviewSize.width * mPreviewSize.height];

                Util.YUV_NV21_TO_BGR(_temp, data, mPreviewSize.width,  mPreviewSize.height);

                bgrImage.getIntBuffer().put(_temp);

                opencv_core.cvTranspose(bgrImage, transposed);
                opencv_core.cvFlip(transposed, transposed, 1);

                opencv_core.cvSetImageROI(transposed, opencv_core.cvRect(0, 0, mPreviewSize.height, mPreviewSize.height));
                opencv_core.cvCopy(transposed, squared, null);
                opencv_core.cvResetImageROI(transposed);

                videoRecorder.setTimestamp(lastSavedframe.getTimeStamp());
                videoRecorder.record(squared);
            }
            catch(com.googlecode.javacv.FrameRecorder.Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        lastSavedframe = new SavedFrames(data, frameTimeStamp);
    }
}
```

This code uses a method "**YUV_NV21_TO_BGR**", which I found from this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacv/zo_pZPgDRNA)

Basically this method is used to resolve, which I call as, **"The Green Devil problem on Android"**, just like yours. I was having the same issue and wasted almost 3-4 days. Before adding "YUV_NV21_TO_BGR" method when I just took transpose of YuvIplImage, more importantly a combination of transpose, flip (with or without resizing), there was **greenish output** in resulting video. This "YUV_NV21_TO_BGR" method saved the day. Thanks to @David Han from above google groups thread.

Also you should know that all this processing (transpose, flip and resize), in onPreviewFrame, takes much time which causes a very serious hit on Frames Per Second (FPS) rate. When I used this code, inside onPreviewFrame method, the resulting FPS of the recorded video was down to 3 frames/sec from 30fps.

I would advise not to use this approach. Rather you can go for post-recording processing (transpose, flip and resize) of your video file using JavaCV in an AsyncTask. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {  
     //IplImage newImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(yuvIplimage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);   
     if (recording) {    
         videoTimestamp = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);                
         yuvimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight * 3 / 2, IPL_DEPTH_8U,1); 
         yuvimage.getByteBuffer().put(data); 

         rgbimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3); 
         opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(yuvimage, rgbimage, opencv_imgproc.CV_YUV2BGR_NV21);      

         IplImage rotateimage=null;
              try {
                    recorder.setTimestamp(videoTimestamp);   
                    int rot=0;
                    switch (degrees) {
                    case 0:
                        rot =1;
                        rotateimage=rotate(rgbimage,rot);
                    break;
                    case 180:
                        rot = -1;
                        rotateimage=rotate(rgbimage,rot);
                        break;                     
                    default:
                        rotateimage=rgbimage;
                }                      
                    recorder.record(rotateimage);

              } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }  
        }

    }
IplImage rotate(IplImage IplSrc,int angle) {
    IplImage img= IplImage.create(IplSrc.height(), IplSrc.width(), IplSrc.depth(), IplSrc.nChannels());
    cvTranspose(IplSrc, img);
    cvFlip(img, img, angle);        
    return img;
    }    
}
```

after many searches this works for me.

Comment: @topcpl its giving me error on line number

         opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(yuvimage, rgbimage, opencv_imgproc.CV_YUV2BGR_NV21);